# Navbar/sidebar on a wordpress site not editable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am helping a non-profit modify their existing wordpress site. The site is very old (built in 2009) and so is the theme ('deFusion'). They wanted me to add a calendar to the sidebar and restructure the navbar. Although I see there are already added items on the sidebar, there is no place in the dashboard where I could add additional items to the the same sidebar. I could not edit the navbar either (add or remove menu items).

How do you deal with an old theme like this? I am not a wordpress expert nor have done any work with PHP. I have searched online but have not been able to find any relevant solution.

Comment: In back-office, you must have a menu "appearance" with sub menus "widgets" and "menu" to edit this configurations. If you don't the appearance menu, you probably haven't the good user access level. You need to be administrator, not just editor

Comment: I have admin privilages. I see the menu and widget pages. One thing I noticed is there is no 'primary location' or 'secondary...' on the theme. I assumed the main navbar on the header is the primary location, but I am not sure how I would go about and edit it without knowing where to do so on the menu page. Is there a plugin that automatically detects the primary and secondary menus and allow you to modify them?